# quick doubt about a complex equation, does my thinking look correct?

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers, circles

$||z|| = 2$, I need to find all possible solutions for this equation.
my attempt:
this is a circle of radius equal to 2, and therefore the solutions lie on the circumference.
is it true?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Considering $z$ as a complex number in the form $z = x + iy$ you have

$$|z| = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} = 2$$

That is

$$x^2 + y^2 = 4$$

As you can see this does describe a circumference of radius $2$, and there are infinite solutions.

**Late add**

Notice that "all" possible solutions are the ones in the form

$$x = \pm \sqrt{4 - y^2}$$

So the vectors of the solutions is given by $v = (\sqrt{4 - y^2}, y)$ and $u = (-\sqrt{4-y^2}, y)$ with $y\in [0, 2]$.